# Change color at Paint and Canvas on Android

Tags: android, android-canvas, paint

Sorry if the question is silly, but I'm new to Android. I read a lot on developer.android.сom, but solutions to my problem is not found, unfortunately.
Most of the code I found on staсkoverflow, finished the part itself.
This View inserted in the Activity in FrameLayout, over the text, and allows you to leave notes in the e-book.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class PaintSurface extends View implements OnTouchListener {

    private Canvas canvas;
    private Path path;
    private Paint paint;
    private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();

    public PaintSurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        this.setOnTouchListener(this);

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.SQUARE);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(16);
        paint.setAlpha(100);
        canvas = new Canvas();
        path = new Path();
        paths.add(path);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        for (Path p : paths) {
            canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
        }

    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            path.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }

    }

    private void touch_up() {
        path.lineTo(mX, mY);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        path = new Path();
        paths.add(path);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;

    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        paint.setColor(color);

    }
}
```

Describe the problem.
I draw the line of the default color, red. Then, use the setColor() changes to green to draw a green line next to the red line. But the first red line also turns green. Such changes occur if you change the style or the stroke width.
How is it possible to paint a different color?

A feeling that in a few months this problem would seem to me ridiculous and stupid, and I myself will feel myself silly and I would be ashamed, but now I do not know how to solve this problem...

Answer (score 10):

The `Paint` color only takes effect when you draw.

From your code you draw all the Paths at once.

```
  for (Path p : paths) {
        canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
  }
```

This takes the same paint object and uses it to draw the paths, using what ever color was set last.

What you need to do is set the color between drawing.

```
   paint.setColor(color.RED); // Will apply to first path.

   for (Path p : paths) {           
        canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
        paint.setColor(color.GREEN); // Will be applied on next Path.
    }
```

A better solution would be

```
   for (Path p : paths) {    
        //Determine Paint color Here.
        paint.setColor(myColor); // where myColor is your variable to use for this layer.
                                 // This could be from an array/List of colors matching to Paths.
        canvas.drawPath(p, paint);          
    }
```

Comment: How would I use this to fix my issue here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521661/change-color-without-affecting-anything-previously-drawn

Answer (score 3):

One thing that you can try is to create one `Paint` object for each path in array List.. This way you can specify different `Paint` properties for each path in ArrayList...

Comment: I read that modifying `Paint` objects is quite costly. Have you seen any performance improvements using an array like this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code it will help to change canvas background color and paint color.I am using this in my app.

```
package com.kidsfingerpainting;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class CanvasView extends View {

    private Paint mPaint;

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private android.graphics.Path mPath;
    private Paint mBitmapPaint;
    private ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    private ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    public static int selectedcolor;
    private Map<Path, Integer> colorsMap = new HashMap<Path, Integer>();

    public CanvasView(Context c, int width, int height) {
        super(c);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFF000000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        mCanvas = new Canvas();
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        selectedcolor = getResources().getColor(R.color.black);

    }

    public CanvasView(Context context, AttributeSet arr) {
        super(context, arr);

    }

    // ////////////////////////all color for brush/////////////////
    public void setPaintMode() {
        mPaint.setColor(0xFF000000);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    }

    public void set_PaintModetrans() {
        mPaint.setColor(0x00000000);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    }

    public void setPaintMode_violet() {
        mPaint.setColor(0xFF8B00FF);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        selectedcolor = getResources().getColor(R.color.violet);
    }

    public void setPaintMode_indigo() {
        mPaint.setColor(0xFF000066);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        selectedcolor = getResources().getColor(R.color.indigo);
    }

    public void setPaintMode_blue() {
        mPaint.setColor(0xFF0000FF);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        selectedcolor = getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
    }

    public void setPaintMode_green() {
        mPaint.setColor(0xFF00FF00);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        selectedcolor = getResources().getColor(R.color.green);
    }

    public void setPaintMode_yellow() {
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFF00);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        selectedcolor = getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow);
    }

    public void setPaintMode_orange() {
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF7F00);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        selectedcolor = getResources().getColor(R.color.orange);
    }

    public void setPaintMode_red() {
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        selectedcolor = getResources().getColor(R.color.red);
    }

    public void setPaintMode_redbg() {
        mCanvas.drawColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setColor(0x00000000);
    }

    public void setPaintMode_pink() {
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF33CC);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        selectedcolor = getResources().getColor(R.color.pink);
    }

    public void setPaintMode_white() {
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        selectedcolor = getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
    }

    public void setPaintMode_black() {
        mPaint.setColor(0xFF000000);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        selectedcolor = getResources().getColor(R.color.black);
    }

    // /////////////////////// all background color set code////////////
    public void setPaintMode_blackbg() {
        mCanvas.drawColor(0xFF000000);
    }

    public void setPaintMode_whitebg() {
        mCanvas.drawColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    }

    public void setPaintMode_pinkbg() {
        mCanvas.drawColor(0xFFFF33CC);
    }

    public void setPaintMode_orangebg() {
        mCanvas.drawColor(0xFFFF7F00);
    }

    public void setPaintMode_yellowbg() {
        mCanvas.drawColor(0xFFFFFF00);
    }

    public void setPaintMode_greenbg() {
        mCanvas.drawColor(0xFF00FF00);
    }

    public void setPaintMode_bluebg() {
        mCanvas.drawColor(0xFF0000FF);

    }

    public void setPaintMode_indigobg() {
        mCanvas.drawColor(0xFF000066);

    }

    public void setPaintMode_violetbg() {
        mCanvas.drawColor(0xFF8B00FF);

    }

    // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void setEraseMode() {
        selectedcolor = getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        for (Path p : paths) {
            mPaint.setColor(colorsMap.get(p));
            canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
        }

        mPaint.setColor(selectedcolor);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 8;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;

    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;

        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        paths.add(mPath);
        colorsMap.put(mPath, selectedcolor);
        mPath = new Path();
        mPath.reset();
        invalidate();

    }

    public void eraseAll() {

        if (mPath != null) {
            paths.clear();
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            // currentMoveList.add(mPath);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();

            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void resetcanvas() {
        mCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, Mode.CLEAR);
    }

    public void onClickUndo() {
        if (paths.size() > 0) {
            undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
            invalidate();
        } else {

        }

    }
}
```

You can call it's any method from activity by doing this.

```
CanvasView canvas = new CanvasView(MainActivity.this, width, height);
        frame_layout.addView(canvas);
```

Paste this in oncreate method.

// set Onclick listener and use following codes

```
undo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.undo);
        undo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                canvas.onClickUndo();

            }
        });
        eraser = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.eraser);
        eraser.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                canvas.setEraseMode();

            }
        });
        clear = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.clear);
        clear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                canvas.eraseAll();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

replace your onTouchEvent and onDraw method or you can use this custom view

```
package com.draw;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawingView extends View {
    private Paint paint;
    private Path path;
    private Paint canvasPaint;
    private Canvas drawCanvas;
    private Bitmap canvasBitmap;

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.init();

        this.paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        this.paint.setStrokeWidth(4f);
        this.paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        this.paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        this.paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    }

    private void init() {
        this.paint = new Paint();
        this.path = new Path();
        this.canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }

    public void setStroke(float width) {
        this.paint.setStrokeWidth(width);
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        this.paint.setColor(color);
    }

    public void reset() {
        this.drawCanvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        this.canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        this.drawCanvas = new Canvas(this.canvasBitmap);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(this.canvasBitmap, 0, 0, this.canvasPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(this.path, this.paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            this.path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            this.path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            this.drawCanvas.drawPath(this.path, this.paint);
            this.path.reset();
            break;

        default:
            return false;
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I have two methods in my DrawingView class, one to change the color when a different color is selected on a color palette. And another that changes the color randomly every few seconds with a handler.

I had to use invalidate() in both methods to sort of refresh what was affected on the main thread and not change anything previously drawn. Works great if you just use invalidate in your methods.

```
    public void setColor(String newColor) {
    //set color
    invalidate();
    paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
}


//random color chosen automatically
public void randomColor () {
    //invalidate needed here for the random color change every 30sec, to not change lines already drawn.
    invalidate();
    paintColor = Color.argb(255, rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256), rand.nextInt(256));
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You describe the right way but when first time select the color, then it working correctly but again change then same problem occurred .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set up hexadecimal code for color in android then here is string

```
 currentPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#B6B6B6"));
```